# Browsers treat localhost pages and external web pages differently?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

Recently I was working on a enhancement of some old codes, and found a interesting case . The source code of the web pages looks like below

```
<FORM method="POST" action="...">
...
<BUTTON onclick="window.location='abc.jsp'">Back</BUTTON>
<BUTTON onclick="submitForm();">Next</BUTTON>
...
</FORM>
```

when I ran it on my local server, say accessing via http://localhost:9081/xyz.jsp , I found the 'Back' button don't work correct. Clicking the button was same as submitting the form!
But if I ran it from a external server , accessing via a location  http://example.com:9081/xyz.jsp , the 'Back' button works just as expected,  Clicking it redirect to 'abc.jsp' .

I'm wondering if it have anything to do with doctype of this page as it is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

I have tested on ie11 & firefox 27.0.1 , both got same result.

Comment: As expected means what? what exactly you are expecting?

Comment: Clicking it redirect to 'abc.jsp' . since the onclick event of this button is bound to this code "window.location='abc.jsp' "